# Sytem.Reflection.Emit error when establishing XML client in Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Trying to establish an xmlrpc to a third party web service from my function app. It works fine from localhost, and indeed, it works in other functions but when published to Azure I'm getting this error:

```
 System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.
   at CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcProxyGen.BuildAssembly(Type itf, String assemblyName, String moduleName, String typeName, AssemblyBuilderAccess access)
   at CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(Type itf)
   at CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcProxyGen.Create[T]()
```

It's failing at this line:

```
 _serviceClient = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IServiceClient>();
```

IServiceClient is an interface that looks like this:

```
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;
using System;

namespace App.Core.Helpers.Service
{
    [XmlRpcUrl("https://some.url")]
    public interface IServiceClient : IXmlRpcProxy

// methods
}
```

I've manually added the System.Reflection.Emit package to the solution in an attempt to fix it, but no joy. The exact same code is running fine in other apps we have in Azure. The app is running .Net framework 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem which can occur when there is an **old version of a DLL still lingering somewhere around**. Make sure that the latest assemblies are deployed and no duplicated older assemblies are hiding in certain folders. Your best bet would be to delete every built item(`Clean Build`) and `Rebuild`/redeploy the entire solution.

**In particular**, be sure an old version is not in the [GAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac). 
This can help to [Remove an Assembly from the Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/working-with-assemblies-and-the-gac).

Comment: Accepting as solution because even though the specific steps suggested did not fix the problem, I do believe that conflicting dlls was the issue. In the end I completely rebuilt the solution, removing all dependencies on other projects and finally it worked. Also thanks for pointing me in the direction of that GAC tool. That was really useful.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same issue as you were facing.
What I found solution is that, I was using asp.net core framework So I have to change it into net 4.5 framework. And that's all.
Issue resolved.
So you may try that.